# Easiest way to test hardware with windows

Tags: windows, hardware

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on an Asus R556L.

I have a problem with my sound card and the seller's technical support wants me to test it with its windows-only official driver.

What is the easiest way to boot into Windows and test the sound card ?

- I think a virtual machine won't be able to use my sound card if it doesn't work on the host OS
- I couldn't find how to put Windows on an external drive
- I thought to create a dual boot with this [tutorial](https://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-windows-after-linux/).

My laptopt has an internal activation Key so no problem for installing windows.

### Solution

Full backup the system and install windows again

### Short sound card problem description

My sound card used to work perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04. Since last week, it hasn't been recognized. It doesn't appear in Pavu Control or Alsa mixer. I tried several tutorials. After booting Ubuntu 16.04 and Fedora 30, I assumed it was faulty hardware.

In the end the sound card needs to be physically fixed.

Comment: The easiest way is to find a live Windows image. Don't ask me where to find it.

Comment: It is possible that your sound device is not supported by Linux.

Comment: I would try the virtual machine first. As I understand it (though I may well be wrong) the actual hardware is made available, so it might work even if it doesn't work on the host.

Comment: @terdon Normally hardware like sound cards will be virtualized (as some generic ac97 or ich9 chip for example). It might be possible to detach the device from your host OS and give your VM direct and exclusive control over it via USB or PCI pass-through (whichever applicable), if your system and hypervisor support this.

Comment: The easiest way is to install Windows, which may not be that easy. It may be easier to troubleshoot the sound card from Ubuntu on your own. Ask a new question with all the information about specific chips used in the soundcard.

Comment: Well I couldn't find a PCI passtrhough tutorial with VirtualBox or Gnome-boxes. Do you have suggestion on tutorials ? The nice thing is that my CPU and motherboard support Intel virtualization optimization !

Comment: [Windows to Go](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview)

Comment: Was the kernel updated recently? Try booting into a previous kernel.

Comment: I had already tried that... In the end I did a full system backup and simply installed windows. It seems to be the easiest way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download Windows10 image from following link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO

It is from Microsoft itself so it is pretty legit, download ISO either burn it or make LiveUSB out of it and install it. The OS will not be activated, however you can use it to test out your sound card.

Another idea I have is to try to use wine to install the driver and test the sound card that way.

Comment: Wine will not work.